# Pass value from Dialog Form to another Form in C#

Tags: c#

I have a C# windows form application. I have a form already opened and I need to open another form as dialog. For example, I have a form "Sell Cars", inside that form I have the fields related to the car (license, model, year, etc.) and a button to open a dialog box with the list of cars to be sold. The user selects one from the list and after that I need to copy all values of the selected car into the main form and close the dialog form.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score -1):

You can access and set variable of any form opened by your main form.

main.cs

```
string result = "";
using(SecondForm secondForm = new SecondForm()) 
{
    if(secondForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
    {
        result = secondForm.carName;
    }
}
```

SecondForm.cs

```
public partial class SecondForm
{
    public string carName;
    public SecondForm(){
        carName = "honda";
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to pass info from SecondForm to main. The SecondForm should be the dialog

Comment: Yeah, so in `main` you'd go `mySecondFormInstance.Car`

Comment: Not sure I follow, sorry. When the user selects the car from dialog, I suppose to dispose that form

Comment: I updated the code. Basically the same concept. You can access form 1 from form 2, and vice versa

Comment: got it, thank you so much